# How to get a base 64 string or byte data of the current excel file, in the excel web addin?

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, excel-web-addins

I am working on an excel web addin wherein I need the **base 64** content or byte data of the currently opened file. Is there any way to get it using javascript/C#. I am creating it using visual studio.
This excel is located on my onedrive account.

Comment: Why JavaScript?

Comment: It's like you are running away from the circus to join the orphanage

Comment: ok Is there anyway to achieve it using C#?